# Why a Set of UITouch?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I was just curious to why the UIResponder method returns a Set of UITouch objects as opposed to just an Array

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

I can't quite wrap my head around what the benefits are or what the purpose behind it. Hoping someone could explain what is happening in the background and how do I eventually end up with a Set of UITouch. For example if I were to drag two fingers across the screen wouldn't that be an Array of UITouch objects?

Comment: "Why" questions tend to be opinion-based. In particular, you're asking why Apple chose to design something a certain way, and they tend not to post official statements on SO. Thus, you won't get an authoritative answer, and the only answers the community can provide are "If I were designing it, I'd have done it this way because...", which is opinion-based.

Comment: I have to edit and rephrase, I guess what I am really asking is what exactly is going on when I get a Set of UITouch

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. The method is called with a set of UITouch objects representing the touches which have moved (two or more for a multi-touch). There is no *order* between the touches which requires them to be stored in an array.

Comment: There is no *order* to the gesture recognizers attached to a view, yet the `gestureRecognizers` property is an array not a set. It is reasonable to ask why the UIKit designers chose to use a set rather than an array for touches (both as the message argument and as the `allTouches` property of `UIEvent`), when other collections in UIKit are arrays when they could be sets.

Comment: I do agree that answers (including mine) to this question are likely to be opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of us can only speculate about why UIKit reports a set rather than an array.

Here's my guess: it emphasizes that the touches aren't in any particular order and might not be in the same order from one event to the next. Since there's no subscript operator for `Set` or `NSSet`, it's harder to make the mistake of storing the index (0, 1, 2, etc.) of a touch for use when processing a later event.

It may also be an implementation detail. UIKit only reports touch events to your app at 60 Hz (on most devices), synchronized with the screen refresh. If the hardware supports reporting touch events more often than 60 Hz, UIKit needs to coalesce multiple events for the same touch. This coalescing occurs automatically, in a sense, if UIKit stores the updated touches as a set instead of as an array.

Answer (score 1):

"Sets" and "Arrays" are both collection objects, so yes, all touches could be returned in either, or a dictionary for that matter.  The reason, I imagine, that Apple chose to return a set is twofold:

1. **Touches are *unique***.  Objects in an array can appear multiple times, in a set they cannot.  Since each touch is only one touch, they make more sense in a set.
2. **Touches are *unordered***.  Objects in an array are ordered, in a set they are not.  How would you fix the order of touches?  Which occurred earlier perhaps?  Or which are leftmost, or most firm, etc... there is no natural correct order so they are unordered, hence best fit to a set.